# Error code 605 while trying to use biometric authentication on Android phone

Tags: javascript, android, visualizer, temenos-quantum, android-biometric-prompt

When I install and run the apk on my device (Samsung Galaxy M30S, Android Q), and request for biometric authentication for login, it throws error code 605. How do I resolve this?

```
Error Code: 605 Error Name: null Message: Error in JavaScript callback invocation at frm1LoginController.js:41
                kony.localAuthentication.authenticate(constants.LOCAL_AUTHENTICATION_MODE_BIOMETRICS, this.statusCB, config);
        Uncaught KonyError:
        errorCode : 605
        name : Unknown Error
        message : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/biometric/BiometricManager;
        Native Stacktrace: 
        ny0k.br.<clinit>(UnknownSource:26)
         *************** 
        JS Stacktrace: 
            at authUsingTouchID (frm1LoginController.js:41:34)
            at getDeviceDetails (frm1LoginController.js:30:14)
            at AS_Button_j49bb142f9ff4f658194e0f98b71e751 (frm1LoginController.js:104:38)
        
            at com.konylabs.vmintf.KonyJavaScriptVM.a(UnknownSource:574)
            at com.konylabs.android.ao.handleMessage(UnknownSource:281)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
            at com.konylabs.android.ad$a.run(UnknownSource:349)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add "USE_FINGERPRINT" permission in project settings.